# DLL object debugging

Tags: debugging, dll, attach-to-process

I have a huge codebase that consists of many modules and one of these modules are using another one as a dll object. Now I want to debug this dll object but i don't know the other module that is using it. Can I do something like the attaching to process debug without knowing the original module that is calling my dll?

Comment: Sure, if you attach to a process and set a breakpoint in the dll, it does not matter who is calling into it for the sake of debugging.

Comment: each module in my code base runs in a process.

Comment: So i don't know which to attach to